# Passing multiple parameters from shell script to mysql query

Tags: mysql, unix

I have to write a unix shell script which will take the parameters for MySQL and export the result into csv file.
I have written to some extent but am unable to pass the multiple parameters from shell script to sql.

Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

assuming you call the script like this
`$ ./script param1 param2 param3`

in the script

```
echo $0 #will echo 'script' (the name of the script)
echo $1 #will echo 'param1'
echo $2 #will echo 'param2'
echo $3 #will echo 'param3'
echo $# #will echo '3' the number of params passed to script
echo $@ #will echo 'param1 param2 param3' (all the parameters passed)
host="127.0.0.1"
user="root"
password="pass"
result=`mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$password --skip-column-names -e "select $param1 from $param2 where $param3 = 3"`
echo $result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -e "set @param1:=4897, @param2:=2; source the_script.sql;"
```

And the script:

```
SELECT @param1, @param2;
```

P.S. BTW, I recommend to pass connection parameters using `--defaults-extra-file` option.